# AWS Elastic Load Balancer DNS Name Change and Route 53 (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk, Route 53 and the eb cli tool `eb init, start, stop etc.`. My Elastic Beanstalk instance is running PHP 5.4 on 64bit Amazon Linux.

I've created a hosted zone in Route 53 and added an alias to point my domain name at the Elastic Load Balancer.  The load balancer that's created when I run the command `eb start`.  I followed these instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowToAliasRRS.html

When I make some config changes (e.g. add a keypair), stop Elastic Beanstalk `eb stop` and start again `eb start` the Load Balancer's DNS name changes and I have to manually change the alias in Route 53.

Is there a way to avoid this or automate updating the alias?

Answer (score 2):

I've published [some sample code here](https://bitbucket.org/aldrinleal/elasticbeanstalk-r53-self-registration) to let your own application do this once if fires up. The code in that project is not fully tested, but should help you get up to speed:

(And if you're using [my plugin](http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin/), [there's a mojo do to that](https://bitbucket.org/aldrinleal/beanstalker/src/tip/beanstalk-maven-plugin/src/main/java/br/com/ingenieux/mojo/beanstalk/dns/BindDomainsMojo.java). this one was well-tested :])

You can call with:

```
$ mvn beanstalk:bind-domains -Dbeanstalk.domains=services.modafocas.org:Z3DJ4DL0DIEEJA
```

Thank you

Comment: Many thanks for this it's helpful. I'm using PHP not Java.. Would you happen to have any advice regarding doing this with PHP? Matthew

Comment: Map the API Calls to PHP instead :)